# Ruby on RailsのネストしたリソースのIDを個別に1からauto incrementさせたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

例えば以下のようなルーティングで実現するようなネストしたリソースにおいて

```
resources :parents do
  resources :children
end
```

それぞれのparentの子リソースであるchildrenに1から始まる番号を付けたい時(/parents/1/children/1/と/parents/2/children/1/は違うリソースを指すようにしたいが、ID自体は1からauto incrementさせたい)はどのような方法が一番良いですか。

Comment: タイトルだけで問題を把握してもらいやすいように、さらには回答をもらいやすいように編集してみました。気にいらないところなどあれば (お手数ですが) [edit]して上書きしてしまってください。

Comment: childのキーは所属するparentのIDとの複合キーということですか？

Comment: そういうことになりますね

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まさに私が意図していた事と同じ質問が英語版のStack Overflowに存在しました (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463891/rails-3-1-nested-resource-with-composite-primary-key-id-parent-id)。

> 一つ考えられる方法は、別のカラムを作って(idはプライマリキーとしてそのまま残しておいて)、そのカラムに親リソースのIDをスコープとした一意性のバリデーションを追加して、そしてbefore_createかafter_createでそのカラムの値を生成することです。
>
> サンプル (実際のコードではない)
>
> ```
> class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
>   ...
>   validates_uniqueness_of :sub_id, :scope => :post_id
>
>   before_create do
>     this.sub_id = post.comments.size + 1
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> そうすれば、sub_idをプライマリキーのように使うことができます。例えば特定のpostのcommentを一つ取得したい時は
>
> ```
> post.comments.where(:sub_id => val).first
> ```
>
> とか
>
> ```
> post.comments.find_by_sub_id(val)
> ```
>
> とかすればいい訳です。注意すべき点は、このコードを実際に使う時はその時々の要件に合わせて変更を加えるべきだという事です。例えば、commentが削除できるのならば、次のsub_idの値を決めるために使うカウンタをpostに保存しておいたほうが良いのかもしれません。

まだ試していないのでまだ分かりませんが、"Composite Primary Keys for ActiveRecords" ([https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys)というgemもこういう場合便利かもしれません](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys)%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86gem%E3%82%82%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E4%BE%BF%E5%88%A9%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)。

Comment: このサンプルコードだと注意点としてあげられている他にも例えば(ほぼ)同時に"Comment"を追加した場合sub_idが重複するなどの問題があります。この手の連番を正しく自作するにはロックやトランザクションを適切に扱う必要があるので実際にはかなり面倒なことになります。